# Can't install El Capitan update 10.11.3 because can't restart normally

Tags: macos, shutdown

I've got the typical problem that OSX can't shutdown/restart normally. I'm on El Capitan but it happened in the past with Mavericks etc. Don't know why they can't fix this...

Anyway, now I want to install El Capitan update 10.11.3, the final step is it wants to restart the system.

I click the 'restart' button but the restart fails.

I can hard boot by holding down the power button... but then the update doesn't finish its install - it still says I need to restart if I go into App Store.

Restart or shutdown from the Apple menu don't work.

I tried a `shutdown -r now` from Terminal... this successfully restarts but the update still 'needs restart' when I go back in after booting.

MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)
El Capitan 10.11.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to complete the update by:

- hard shutdown (hold down power button)
- boot into safe mode (hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> when powering on)
- open App Store and click Restart for the uncompleted update

was then able to restart successfully from safe mode, completing the update